# Unity3D and Daydream Controller - Android build issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

I can't create an Android build with the Daydream Controller demo.

In Unity it is working, but when I try to create an Android build, I have errors in the console.

[The errors I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJkGr.png)

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
```

I am using Windows 10, Unity 5.3.2f1.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Studio, SDK Manager. Remove the Android Build tool. Then, start your Unity and build the apps. It would ask you to update the Android SDK. Then click "Yes". It should works after